# Using both Blueprint and Spring (Not spring-dm) with OSGi

Tags: spring, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I have a Spring3 application which takes about 3 minutes to load a big domain model on startup... this is fine when the application is deployed to a production environment every once in a while but its a massive pain when making development changes due to the stopping/starting of the application.

I've done a bit of investigation and I like the idea of separating my application in modules using OSGi so that I can deploy only the parts of my application which are changing (e.g. No need to deploy the Domain Model when I'm making changes to the Persistence layer); However I've found the barrier to entry for OSGi to be quite high.

Is it possible to use both Blueprint to inject the services provided between modules (e.g to expose implementations of the domain model to my web tier) and to continue to use the Spring framework (not Spring Dynamic Modules) inside each of my modules?

Comment: Why blueprint for this? And why not spring-dm? Your alternatives are Blueprint Aries (which isn't spring based so not as easy to integrate with) and Eclipse Gemini (which is the replacement for Spring-DM, and /is/ Spring based).

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix blueprint and spring. They are two separate technologies that are similar but incompatible.

I would also not recommend using spring dm in OSGi. While it works for some simple cases it has a horrible classloading model that leads to massive problems in OSGi. See [this article from Guillaume Nodet](http://gnodet.blogspot.de/2010/03/spring-dm-aries-blueprint-and-custom.html). Besides that spring dm was abandoned by springsource. There are not even bug fixes since ages.

Spring Gemini is also practically abandoned. Springsource donated it to eclipse and then ceased to really work on it.

So if you want to go this step to OSGi you will have to switch to aries blueprint or to declarative services. So do not underestimate the effort.